# How typing the correct path to my json file inside a javascript file

Tags: javascript, json, django, xmlhttprequest

python 3.6.4 , django 2.0

I have a [index.html](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JTN9G8m3bssNI54VxiqoRWUcZkhDV6uD) which load this javascript file [script.js](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SK7kcXGTllCmBpZ2FRQGyv6QRmI4j9U1) and inside this i have problems to type the correct path to one json file [data.json](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c44WZBTyDvKFq6dXaZDy3lCTW6EGuI2o).

The index.html now is displayed without the information from data.json , I am using  a XmlHttpRequest object.

```
function makeRequest(url){
...
    http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http_request.open('GET', url, true);
}
...
window.onload = function(){
    makeRequest("here/have/problems");
}
```

**Tree of my files**
[image]

inside index.html I am using

```
{% load static %}
...
<script src="{% static 'bar/scripts/script.js' %}"></script>
```

and that work well, then inside script.js was trying typing "bar/data/data.json" but doesn't work. Guide me please in the correct way about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the full path, including the leading slash - so "/static/bar/data/data.json".

One possible practice to avoid hard-coding that full path is to use the `{% static %}` tag to set a global JS variable in a standalone `<script>` block inside your template.

Answer (score -1):

To go up a directory level, use two dots followed by a slash ("`../`"). You need to go up two directory levels to get out of `templates/bar/`.

```
{% static '../../bar/scripts/script.js'%}
```

Comment: `templates/bar` is not relevant at all here, because it is completely internal to the Django app. The relevant thing is the URL that the view is being served on.